# C - How does sizeof() of a function call works?

Tags: c, function-pointers, sizeof

I have a following line in C:

```
printf("size of sizeof is %d\n", sizeof(printf("lol!\n")));
```

Am I getting the size of a function pointer here?

Comment: No, it is the size of an expression, in this case the return value, which is an int. (and the funtion will not be called, only the type of its return value will be evaluated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `sizeof` evaluates the return type of `printf`. (Here an `int`)

Answer (score -1):

printf() returns no. of char like "lol!" has four character + null char(1) so it will return value 5(an int). And then sizeof() will return sizeof(int) i.e. 4